# Check if start time and end time partially overlapping using MYSQL php yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, yii2

folks
I have been trying to figure out how can I check partial overlapping between two times.
Basically, my timings are saving in a database like this:-
[image]

```
Batch::find()->alias('batch')->joinWith([
            'batchTeachers as teacher',
            'attendanceDates as attendanceDates',
            'batchTiming as batchTiming'
        ])->where([
            'OR', [
                'IN',
                'teacher.teacher_id',
                $teacher_id
            ],
            [
                'IN',
                'batch.teacher_id',
                $teacher_id
            ]
        ])->andWhere([
            'attendanceDates.date' => $date
        ])->andWhere([
            'OR',
            [
                'AND',
                [
                    '>=',
                    'batchTiming.start_time',
                    $calenderStartTime
                ],
                [
                    '<=',
                    'batchTiming.end_time',
                    $calenderEndTime
                ]

            ], [
                'AND', [
                    '<=',
                    'attendanceDates.start_time',
                    $calenderEndTime
                ], [
                    '>=',
                    'attendanceDates.end_time',
                    $calenderEndTime
                ]
            ]

        ])->exists()
```

Raw SQL of the above query is:

```
SELECT `batch`.* FROM `tbl_batch` `batch` LEFT JOIN `tbl_attendance_batch_teacher` `teacher` ON `batch`.`id` = `teacher`.`batch_id` LEFT JOIN `tbl_attendance_date` `attendanceDates` ON `batch`.`id` = `attendanceDates`.`batch_id` LEFT JOIN `tbl_batch_timing` `batchTiming` ON `batch`.`id` = `batchTiming`.`batch_id` WHERE ((`teacher`.`teacher_id`=1294) OR (`batch`.`teacher_id`=1294)) AND (`attendanceDates`.`date`='2021-01-06') AND (((`batchTiming`.`start_time` >= '08:00:00') AND (`batchTiming`.`end_time` <= '09:00:00')) OR ((`attendanceDates`.`start_time` <= '09:00:00') AND (`attendanceDates`.`end_time` >= '09:00:00'))) ORDER BY `date`
```

My problem is if the user has a batch between 9 am to 11 am

If he is busy from 9 am to 11 am then **full** overlapping (RED COLOR)

if he is busy from 9 to 10 am then **partial** overlapping (BLUE COLOR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CASE WHEN statement in your SQL SELECT

```
SELECT
    ` batch `.*,
        CASE
                WHEN ( ` batchTiming `.` start_time ` >= '08:00:00' AND ` batchTiming `.` end_time ` <= '09:00:00' ) THEN 1 -- partial overlap
                WHEN ( ` attendanceDates `.` start_time ` <= '09:00:00' AND ` attendanceDates `.` end_time ` >= '09:00:00' ) THEN 2 -- full overlap
                ELSE 0 -- no overlap
        END as overlap_value

FROM
```

Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

Further to convert it to Active Query add select clause like below...

```
Batch::find()
    ->alias('batch')
    ->select([ 'T.*', 'othrTable.*', ' CASE STATEMENT HERE as overlap_value'])
    ->joinWith( [...
```

And add $overlap_value as a property in your batch model.

Comment: thanks for sharing this but is there any way to convert this is ActiveQuery ?